# No route matches [POST] "/users/1/contacts/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

app/views/contacts/new.html.erb

```
<h2>Add New Contact</h2>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
      <%= simple_form_for @contact, :url => new_user_contact_path do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :first_name %>
          <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :last_name %>
          <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :date_of_birth, as: :date,  discard_year:true, order:[:day, :month] %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :sex %>
          <%= f.select :sex, [:male, :female], class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :phone_number %>
          <%= f.text_field :phone_number, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :address %>
          <%= f.text_area :address, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.button :submit, "Submit", class: "btn btn-success btn-md btn-block" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%= link_to "Back", user_contacts_path %>
```

My routes when I run `rake routes`

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
            new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#new
                user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#create
        destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                   devise/sessions#destroy
               user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#create
           new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)               devise/passwords#new
          edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)              devise/passwords#edit
                             PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
                             PUT    /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
    cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                     devise/registrations#cancel
           user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#create
       new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                    devise/registrations#new
      edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                       devise/registrations#edit
                             PATCH  /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#update
                             PUT    /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#update
                             DELETE /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#destroy
               user_contacts GET    /users/:user_id/contacts(.:format)          contacts#index
                             POST   /users/:user_id/contacts(.:format)          contacts#create
            new_user_contact GET    /users/:user_id/contacts/new(.:format)      contacts#new
           edit_user_contact GET    /users/:user_id/contacts/:id/edit(.:format) contacts#edit
                user_contact GET    /users/:user_id/contacts/:id(.:format)      contacts#show
                             PATCH  /users/:user_id/contacts/:id(.:format)      contacts#update
                             PUT    /users/:user_id/contacts/:id(.:format)      contacts#update
                             DELETE /users/:user_id/contacts/:id(.:format)      contacts#destroy
                       users GET    /users(.:format)                            users#index
                             POST   /users(.:format)                            users#create
                    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                        users#new
                   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                   users#edit
                        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#show
                             PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                        users#destroy
                       index GET    /index(.:format)                            redirect(301, /)
                        root GET    /                                           high_voltage/pages#show {:id=>"index"}
                        page GET    /pages/*id                                  high_voltage/pages#show
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users

      resources :users do
        resources :contacts
      end
    end
```

My `new` and `create` action in `ContactsController`

```
     def new
        @contact = Contact.new
      end

      def create
        @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
        @contact.user = current_user
        if @contact.save
          flash[:success] = "Contact was successfully created!"
          redirect_to @contact.user
        else
          render :new
        end
      end
```

This is the issue:
I get the error: `No route matches [POST] "/users/1/contacts/new"` when I submit the form at http://localhost:3000/users/1/contacts/new. What could be the issue?

Comment: you're just posting to the wrong route. anything with a /new at the end is typically a `get`. The create route isn't going to end in `new`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
 <%= simple_form_for @contact, :url => new_user_contact_path do |f| %>
```

should be:

```
 <%= simple_form_for @contact, :url => user_contacts_path do |f| %>
```

Comment: When I do that I get the error: unintialized UsersControllers. Is that supposed to happen? Considering the fact that I am using devise.

Comment: I believe this should be hitting the contacts controller: `POST   /users/:user_id/contacts(.:format)         contacts#create` Are you sure you need to nest the contacts resources inside user? I don't know the logic of your app. It's possible to make contacts to belong to the creating user without nesting the route and I think it's cleaner to leave the resources separate.

Comment: Could you post your `routes.rb`?

Comment: The logic of the app is that a user has many contacts and contacts belongs to a user. Its just a simple web app to testing download to pdf functionality. The routes.rb is above.

Comment: Yeah--I wouldn't nest the contact routes and just set the user_id to the current_user 's id before creating a contact. Then on the contact show page just define contact instance var as current_user.contacts.

Comment: Okay. I'll do that and get back to you.

Comment: that should then make the create path contacts_path and the user controller is irrelevant for this.